# Long polling with JQuery ajax and Spring DeferredResult returns blank result

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to use Spring's `DeferredResult` to perform long polling. The controller looks like this:

```
package com.example.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult;

import com.example.controller.interfaces.ExampleControllerInterface;

@Component
public class ExampleController implements ExampleControllerInterface{

    @Override
    public String viewHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, HttpSession session){
        return "index";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pollContent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DeferredResult<String> pollContent(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, HttpSession session){

        System.out.println("Polling content.");

        final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();

        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping for 10 seconds.");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Setting result.");
        result.setResult("testing");

        }
        }.start();

        System.out.println("Returning result.");
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm using JQuery's `ajax()` function to access the async `pollContent()` controller function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Spring Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function pollContent() {
        $.ajax({url: "pollContent", success: function(result){
            console.log("Polled result: " + result);
            $("#polledContent").html(result);
        }});
    }
    $(pollContent);
    </script>
  </head>

<body>
    <p>This example uses JQuery's ajax() function to access a Spring controller's async function. After the page loads, it should return in 10 seconds and change the below text:</p>
    <p id="polledContent">Loading...</p>
    <p>Instead, the call returns immediately and the result is blank.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the `ajax()` call to take 10 seconds to return to its success handler, and then to populate the `polledContent` `p` tag with the result.

Instead, the `ajax()` call returns immediately, and the result is blank. The controller function does proceed to set and return the result, but that result doesn't appear to "go" anywhere on the client side.

I'm using annotation configuration instead of web.xml, and I've enabled async in my config class:

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan({"com.example.controller", "com.example.config"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
        super.configureDefaultServletHandling(configurer);
    }
}
```

Edit: As requested, here is the logger output:

```
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (FrameworkServlet.java:1043) - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@49da6e5
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:838) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/SpringExample/]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:1095) - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@3da4a56] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:246) - Looking up handler method for path /
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:284) - Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/] : [{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:251) - Returning handler method [public abstract java.lang.String com.example.controller.interfaces.ExampleControllerInterface.viewHomePage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)]
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:249) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'exampleController'
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:1135) - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@5fe4ef74]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:1135) - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter@c041485]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:1135) - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@24adb017]
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:925) - Last-Modified value for [/SpringExample/] is: -1
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:130) - Invoking [$Proxy20.viewHomePage] method with arguments [org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@49da6e5, {}, org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2f88f324]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) - Method [viewHomePage] returned [index]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler@5c39d55e] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelMethodProcessor@20c740be] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ViewMethodReturnValueHandler@7cd737e7] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor@77170f30] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpHeadersReturnValueHandler@6516a7a9] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.CallableMethodReturnValueHandler@25b98d19] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler@2cb6fe5a] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AsyncTaskMethodReturnValueHandler@b7a0149] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor@45accbf1] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@68f7a9ab] supports [class java.lang.String]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler@495843fd] supports [class java.lang.String]
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:1218) - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'index'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractView.java:261) - Rendering view with name 'index' with model {} and static attributes {}
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (InternalResourceView.java:207) - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'index'
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (FrameworkServlet.java:1053) - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@49da6e5
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (FrameworkServlet.java:991) - Successfully completed request
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:331) - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/SpringExample/]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[DB17A129B0B4A37F85D65A1B973EBF3D]; user=[null]; time=[8ms]; status=[OK]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (FrameworkServlet.java:1043) - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@49da6e5
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (DispatcherServlet.java:838) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/SpringExample/pollContent]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (DispatcherServlet.java:1095) - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@3da4a56] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:246) - Looking up handler method for path /pollContent
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:284) - Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/pollContent] : [{[//pollContent],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:251) - Returning handler method [public abstract org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String> com.example.controller.interfaces.ExampleControllerInterface.pollContent(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)]
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:249) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'exampleController'
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (DispatcherServlet.java:1135) - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@5fe4ef74]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (DispatcherServlet.java:1135) - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter@c041485]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (DispatcherServlet.java:1135) - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@24adb017]
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (DispatcherServlet.java:925) - Last-Modified value for [/SpringExample/pollContent] is: -1
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver@757b2cca] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver@2c353cf8] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver@208b37e2] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@40d0b02b] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMethodArgumentResolver@47d7bd17] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@4421f1b1] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor@17a83b8d] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@6ff67550] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver@36ac04ff] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver@b23433c] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver@b325664] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver@72dcde94] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver@426c7ec5] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver@5c68f351] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver@757b2cca] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver@2c353cf8] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver@208b37e2] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@40d0b02b] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMethodArgumentResolver@47d7bd17] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@4421f1b1] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor@17a83b8d] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@6ff67550] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver@36ac04ff] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver@b23433c] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver@b325664] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver@72dcde94] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver@426c7ec5] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver@5c68f351] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletResponseMethodArgumentResolver@69f4b041] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor@5d9983f8] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RedirectAttributesMethodArgumentResolver@423d0dc5] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelMethodProcessor@e87db7b] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MapMethodProcessor@1f101f10] supports [class org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver@757b2cca] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver@2c353cf8] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver@208b37e2] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@40d0b02b] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMethodArgumentResolver@47d7bd17] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@4421f1b1] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor@17a83b8d] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@6ff67550] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver@36ac04ff] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver@b23433c] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver@b325664] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver@72dcde94] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver@426c7ec5] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:90) - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver@5c68f351] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:130) - Invoking [$Proxy20.pollContent] method with arguments [org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@49da6e5, {}, org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2f88f324]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) - Method [pollContent] returned [null]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler@5c39d55e] supports [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String>]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelMethodProcessor@20c740be] supports [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String>]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ViewMethodReturnValueHandler@7cd737e7] supports [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String>]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor@77170f30] supports [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String>]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpHeadersReturnValueHandler@6516a7a9] supports [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String>]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.CallableMethodReturnValueHandler@25b98d19] supports [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String>]
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler@2cb6fe5a] supports [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String>]
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (DispatcherServlet.java:1012) - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (FrameworkServlet.java:1053) - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@49da6e5
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (FrameworkServlet.java:991) - Successfully completed request
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:331) - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/SpringExample/pollContent]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[DB17A129B0B4A37F85D65A1B973EBF3D]; user=[null]; time=[19ms]; status=[OK]
Polling content.
Returning result.
Sleeping for 10 seconds.
Setting result.
```

I've created a maven project on GitHub if you want to run this yourself, available here: https://github.com/KevinWorkman/SpringExample

I might just be misunderstanding how long polling is performed using Spring and ajax, or I might be missing something that's required. My questions are:

- Why doesn't the async controller function return the proper result to the client?
- What do I have to change to make long polling work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed two concepts: [`@Async` method calls](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) and [asynchronous request processing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async) within Spring MVC's stack. Although both involve the term *asynchronous*, they have different goals (or rather are part of different feature sets).

`@Async` allows for a method's code to be invoked on a separate thread. Spring achieves this by proxying your object and delegating the actual invocation the the real object on another thread. Given

```
@Component
class Real {
    @Async
    public void method() {}
}
```

and

```
Real proxy = ... // get Real from ApplicationContext
proxy.method(); // returns immediately
// continue in this thread
```

The `proxy` looks something like

```
class RealProxy extends Real {
    private ExecutorService executorService; // potentiall configured in Async configuration
    private Real target; // the actual object
    @Override
    public void method() {
        executorService.submit(() -> target.method());
    }
}
```

This is simple enough to understand with `void` methods. With non-void method, however, we need a convention. As the documentation linked above states

> Even methods that return a value can be invoked asynchronously.
>   However, such methods are required to have a `Future` typed return
>   value.

Your method has a return type of `DeferredResult`, which is not a `Future`. Spring, in this case, doesn't complain, but simply returns `null` after dispatching the invocation to another thread.

This is where Spring MVC comes in to play. Spring uses a list of `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` objects to handle return values from `@RequestMapping` annotated handler methods. For `DeferredResult`, that is [`DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler.html). If it receives `null` as a return value, it assumes the request was handled and nothing further needs to be done (this is a common convention among `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`s).

`DeferredResult` is analogous to Java 8's `CompletableFuture` type. It's a promise for a result. By returning a value of type `DeferredResult`, you're promising Spring MVC that you'll have a value at some point (hopefully before it times out). In the meantime, you've dispatched the actual handling to another thread (which will set the value) and the MVC stack can reclaim the request handling thread and have it serve other requests.

To summarize, don't use both of these techniques. Get rid of the `@Async` and un-comment the new `Thread` code you have (though you can use a dedicated thread pool). Spring MVC will receive this `DeferredResult`, it will assume you'll make good on your promise, stash it for later. When you eventually `setResult`, this will notify Spring to unstash and complete the request processing.

---

Looking at your github project, you'll need to enable async support

```
springDispatcher.setAsyncSupported(true);
```

You also don't need to load a `ContextLoaderListener`. Get rid of that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, when I remove the `@Async` annotation and do the `sleep(10000)` and `result.setResult("testing")` on another Thread, I still get the same empty result.

Comment: @KevinWorkman It works for me on Spring 4.x. Please edit your question with your attempt. Also, enable DEBUG logging and check what Spring does.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Also, upgrade to web-app version 3.1. See [Servlet 3.1](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2013/06/04/java-ee-7-deployment-descriptors/)

Comment: I am using Spring 4.0.5, and I've upgraded to web-app version 3.1, but I still see the same error. I do have async enabled via the `@EnableAsync` annotation on the `WebConfig` class (and if I remove it, it throws an exception).  I've edited the post to include my updated code and the log output. I've also updated the GitHub project.

Comment: @KevinWorkman See the end of my answer for enabling async support at the Servlet level, not at the Spring level. Notice your logs show `Invoking [$Proxy20.pollContent] method` and `Method [pollContent] returned [null]`. You're still running the code that has `@Async`.

Comment: I think I had to remove the `@EnableAsync` annotation from my WebConfig class when I added the `springDispatcher.setAsyncSupported(true);` line. It seems to be working now, thanks! This is part of a much larger project (hence the leftover ContextLoaderListener), so I'll try to incorporate this into that and accept your answer if that works.